# What is the correct way to stream frames over udp sink using gstreamer in python?

Tags: python, opencv, udp, gstreamer

I am reading frames from a USB camera using gstreamer (v4l2) and reading it using cv2.videoCapture. It works fine. I want to dump these frames using udp sink and gi. What is the correct way to achieve it? Following is my code, it works but after few minutes I get hugh lag. Kindly let me know what mistake I am doing. Thanks!

```
import cv2
import gi
import numpy as np
import time

gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject, GLib

Gst.init(None)
pipeline_str = ("appsrc name=source ! tiovxdlcolorconvert ! video/x-raw,format=NV12 ! queue ! jpegenc ! multipartmux boundary=spionisto ! rndbuffersize max=65000 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8081 sync=false")
pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(pipeline_str)
source = pipeline.get_by_name("source")
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

##### gst input pipelin
gst_pipeline = 'v4l2src device=/dev/video-usb-cam0 io-mode=2 ! image/jpeg, width=1280, height=720 ! jpegdec ! tiovxdlcolorconvert ! video/x-raw, format=NV12 ! \
    tiovxmultiscaler ! video/x-raw, format=NV12 ! tiovxdlcolorconvert ! video/x-raw, format=RGB ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! queue ! appsink'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gst_pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

try:
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        t1 = time.time()
        raw_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# #############################################################
        gst_buffer = Gst.Buffer.new_wrapped(raw_frame.tobytes())
############################################################
        caps = Gst.caps_from_string(f"video/x-raw,format=RGB,width={frame.shape[1]},height={frame.shape[0]}")
        source.set_property("caps", caps)
        source.emit("push-buffer", gst_buffer)

        t2 = time.time()

        print('FPS : ', 1/(t2-t1))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    # Stop the pipeline and clean up
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    cap.release()
```